# Google Wallet integration on Android App

Tags: java, android, paypal, android-pay

I am working on a Android application where i have to implement automatic payment on button click like Uber Cab app has to pay for taxi fare. Uber Cab is using Google wallet for payment gateway which is very good. 
I want to use Google wallet because to use Paypal customer should have insert card details everytime. But not in the case of Google wallet.

I am not getting good resource to implement Google wallet on my application. 
I need your help.

Comment: Please read the rules of this site : http://stackoverflow.com/tour   You have to ask specific questions about programming.

Comment: See [Google Developers -> Commerce](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The Uber Android app is using the Google Wallet Instant Buy API.

You can find Instant Buy API details including sample implementations at the URL below:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/

You will need to request API access using this form:

http://getinstantbuy.withgoogle.com/

Comment: @Mihai Ionescu Page not found for https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/